# python audiotools open from memory

Tags: python, audio

```
import urllib2
import audiotools

file = urllib2.urlopen('http://test.com/1.mp3')
audio = audiotools.open( file ) # <- error
```

Can I give file from memory (not from drive) to audiotools? 
Or is here any way to load mp3-file from url to audiotools? Without saving it on the harddisk.

Comment: When you encounter an error and ask for help, it'd be nice if you actually include what the error said.

Comment: Sorry :) I know that audiotools.open( filename ) accepts only string as input, but I want to use binary raw from file instead of filename.

Comment: What platform are we on?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/audiotools/__init__.py", line 1387, in open
    f = file(filename, "rb")
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found

Comment: We are on Ubuntu/Python 2.7/audiotools 2.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a limitation of audiotools, and not a trivial one to work around.  See for example the MP3Audio class (https://github.com/tuffy/python-audio-tools/blob/master/audiotools/mp3.py).  The filename is passed all the way down, through multiple layers of the library.  So it pretty much has to be a bona fide filename (i.e. one that can be `open()`'d.

The only thing that comes to mind if you are desperate for a solution is to make a file that is not disk-backed.  For example, `/dev/shm` is a mount point on many Linux systems that does not refer to a real disk, but only to memory.  So you can write your audio file to `/dev/shm/foo.mp3` and then tell audiotools to open that.